# Why do so many Christian religions claim The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (Mormons) are not Christian?

Tags: lds, christology, terminology, comparative-christianity, theosis

What does the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints lack in Christ oriented teachings or doctrine to be considered a Christian church for those who claim otherwise?

Maybe it's not what they lack in teaching but what they teach that changes the definition of Christ. What would those be?

My thoughts on the biggest issue I could find of making God to be more humanlike:

This church teaches Christ to be the Savior of the world, the God of Salvation, the Author of faith, the Creator, etc. They teach Christ as a mediator between us and God the Father as Christ taught. They have separated God the Father and Jesus Christ as two separate persons with separate bodies. They have also declared that getting a body is a step of glorification and making one holy. Another way of saying making us more like God. All of these are scripturally founded in the bible.

To DEHUMANIZE some one is permission to treat them less than yourself. An evil to Christian ideals and an evil that God does not practice. Christ taught contrary to dehumanizing ideals and lifted all people to an equal ground of worth and relationship to Himself.

If making God more like us or God's desire to make us more like Him is the issue, why does this ideal not conflict with Christ's teachings or the bible? We were created in their image, the prophets reference God as having a head, hands, arms, a heart, tears, eyes, ears, etc. all over the bible. From what I can tell, the prophets in the bible spent a lot of time emphasizing the likeness of God and ourselves being married to him and he being jealous of our thoughts and desires. Not to some vague unidentified creature we call God but to a defined creature that resembles us so we can relate to and enjoin with God.

God has spent a lot of effort to humanize us into beings he loves and wants to be one with us as Christ and God the Father are one. This has settled this issue for me in that there is no conflict of Christ's teachings and believing we can become like Him thereby making this concept Christian at heart. Christ was killed for teaching this. Any dogma to preach otherwise is to demean God's creation, destroy the relationship God is creating, and dehumanizes mankind to a state less than their potential / purpose which seems the intent of a Satanic work, not a Christian ideal.

Comment: related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84344/are-there-any-christian-denominations-that-consider-lds-mormons-to-be-christia and https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84052/do-lds-believers-not-accept-any-others-who-self-identify-as-christian

Comment: also related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14633/22319, maybe has the answer you're looking for

Comment: They just have too many differences on the fundamentals from the received Christian tradition. And Judaism very early on concluded that God the Father does not have a body.

Comment: @BrycePackard-*He that hath the Son hath life!  He who does not have the Son of God does not have life* (1 John 5:12) The Elders in Salt Lake have admitted that the Jesus of Mormonism is NOT the Jesus of the Bible! So if one worships the wrong Jesus, one's religion is in vain. No biblical Jesus, no eternal life. It's that simple. Seek the God of the Bible, and live. Keep studying the KJV Bible until you find the real Jesus. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: @raygrant do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: @depperm-I will look it up.  In the mean time: Jesus of the Bible is eternal God   (Trinity).  By shedding of whose blood ALL  receive salvation.  He is spirit who became temporarily incarnated.... Mormonism teaches that Jesus and Satan are brothers, born from the Father and His woman, that He has flesh and blood body; man who became a god and rules over a planet with many wives, and children.  There are sins the blood of Jesus cannot save, but some must shed their own blood (that is why the death penalty by firing squad  is implemented in Utah. That is not the teaching of the Bible.

Comment: those who don't believe in the trinity have biblical basis as well see: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18043/22319 and https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/57432/22319

Comment: @raygrant Off-topic maybe, but "He is spirit who became temporarily incarnated" - I have doubts about "temporarily" being the mainstream doctrine.

Comment: John 5:19: "Then answered Jesus and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father do: for what things soever he doeth, these also doeth the Son likewise." How then is it said truly that "the Word was made flesh" (John 1:14) if the Father did not also do this?

If Lucifer (who fell from heaven) is not the brother of Christ, of what creation is he? Who is his father? How can their be a creation (from the biblical perspective) outside of what God has created?